# Eclipse import suggestions have disappeared

Tags: java, eclipse

I have upgraded a couple of days ago to eclipse 4.2, and am working on a project that is tracked by git using the eGit plugin.

Suddenly, I think it must have been right after a commit with a push, the automatic import hints have completely forgotten about the classes of my project. All it can give hints for are the java standard library classes.

I've tried restarting eclipse, as well as cleaning the project, validating it, performing a pull, and looking at the .classpath file (which didn't look particularly odd to me).

If you look at the screenshot; in the package explorer you can see a class listed named SceneNode". On the right there is a file I was working on, which is in the same project, but which is missing the import option, which should be there.

Manually writing the import statement fixes the problem, but since I'm lazy I want my import options back. Has anyone else had this problem?

[image: my problem]

edit: here's my .classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="jars/jinput.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="jars/lwjgl.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY" value="ORRE-v2/natives"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="jars/lzma.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="jars/slick-util.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="jars/slick.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="jars/xom-1.2.8.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.junit.JUNIT_CONTAINER/4"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="jars/lwjgl_util.jar"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: Maybe show the .classpath file contents?

Comment: @nitind: I added the .classpath file. I compared it to the classpath files of some other projects, and it looks normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Go to *Preferences » Java » Editor » Content Assist » Advanced*.

Make sure *Other Java Proposals* is ticked/checked.

If that does not work simply close the project and reopen it.

Comment: I've selected everything in there, applied my changes, and restarted eclipse. It still doesn't show the import hints :( I suspect that the problem has to do with that eclipse somehow has lost track of the classes in the project, not so much that the hints are turned off in the settings; it's actually the first time I've seen that settings page.

Comment: if the problem is still there after checking options and closing n opening of project then i think the eclipse IDE has some installation problems. You should re-install it by downloading from their official website

Comment: i have search alot but i think you should try eclipse shortcut to fix all imports, if it works.
shortcut is "CTRL+SHIFT+O"

Answer (score 1):

> i have search alot but i think you should try eclipse shortcut to fix all imports, if it works. shortcut is "CTRL+SHIFT+O" – vicky

I couldn't find *Other Java Proposals*, however trying the above worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Updating @vicky's answer for 2020, in Eclipse, to activate the automatic creation of imports for Alexa skills, make sure on the Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced, that all of the Java options under the Default Proposal Kinds are checked.

[image: Advanced Content Assist]

Answer (score 0):

If the issue arises automatically then just restart the eclipse it will work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Preferences » Java » Editor » Content Assist"
Under "Insertion, Add import instead of qualfied name":

Uncheck "Use static imports".

I was coding:

```
FileInputStream instm = new FileInputStream(configpath);
```

Now Eclipse suggests `import java.io.FileInputStream;`.